How can one stop a huddle on Slack?
Example:

How can one stop a huddle on Slack?

I don't see any option:


Huddles continue as long as there remains at least one person in it.
A person that starts a Huddle can leave it and it will continue until no one remains.
You can't stop a Huddle arbitrarily, even if you were the person who started it.
You can leave it by clicking Leave in the channel or DM where it is located.
Resource: Use Huddles in Slack
